# Dereferencing void * just as (int) -- standard practice?

Tags: c, multithreading, void

I was trying to print a thread's return value and discovered that I'm still quite confused by the notion of double void-pointers.

My understanding was that a void* is a pointer to any datatype that can be dereferenced with an appropriate cast, but otherwise the "levels" of referencing are preserved like with regular typed pointers (i.e. you can't expect to get the same value that you put into `**(int **)depth2` by dereferencing it only once like `*depth2`. ).

In the code (below) that I have scraped together for my thread-return-print, however, it seems that I'm *not dereferencing* a **void pointer** at all when I'm just casting it to **(int)**. Is this a case of an address being used as value? If so, is this the normal way of returning from threads? Otherwise, what am I missing??

(I am aware that the safer way to manipulate data inside the thread might be caller-level storage, but I'm quite interested in this case and what it is that I don't understand about the void pointer.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *myThread(void *arg)
{
    return (void *)42;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    void *res;                                        // res is itself a void *

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, &res);                          // i pass its address, so void** now
    printf(" %d \n", (int)res);                       // how come am i able to just use it as plain int?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Passing the address of `res` to `pthread_join` allows `pthread_join` to change the value of `res`. If the call was simply `pthread_join(tid, res)`, then `pthread_join` would not be able to modify `res`. Other than that, your example boils down to `void *res = (void *)42` followed by `int n = (int)res`. Converting an `int` to a `void *` and back to an `int` is (technically speaking) not guaranteed to work. But with small integer values, it generally works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the purpose of `pthread_join()` is to update the `void *`
given through its second argument in order to obtain the result of the
thread function (a `void *`).
When you need to update an `int` as in `scanf("%d", &my_var);` the argument
is the address of the `int` to be updated: an `int *`.
With the same reasoning, you update a `void *` by providing a `void **`.

In the specific situation of your example, we don't use the returned
`void *` in a normal way: this is a trick!
Since a pointer can be thought about as a big integer counting the bytes in
a very long row, the trick is to assume that this pointer can simply store
an integer value which does no refer to any memory location.

In your example, returning `(void *)42`, is equivalent to saying
"you will find something interesting at address 42".
But nothing has ever been placed at this address!
Is this a problem? No, as long as nobody tries to dereference this
pointer in order to retrieve something at address 42.

Once `pthread_join()` has been executed, the variable `res` has
been updated and contains the returned `void *`: 42 in this case.
We perform here the reverse-trick by assuming that the information memorised
in this pointer does not refer to a memory location but is a simple integer.

It works but this is very ugly!
The main advantage is that you avoid the expensive cost of malloc()/free()

```
void *myThread(void *arg)
{
  int *result=malloc(sizeof(int));
  *result=42;
  return result;
}

...
int *res;
pthread_join(tid, &res);
int result=*res; // obtain 42
free(res);
```

A better solution to avoid this cost would be to use the parameter
of the thread function.

```
void *myThread(void *arg)
{
  int *result=arg;
  *result=42;
  return NULL;
}

...
int expected_result;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, &expected_result);
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
// here expected_result has the value 42
```

Comment: I just ran this, and i think in the last line of the last code example, should maybe be 
```pthread_join(tid, NULL)``` instead of ```&tid```?

Comment: @tractatusviii Yes, sorry about that. You are perfectly right. I just edited consequently.

Comment: "_Since a pointer can be thought about as a big integer ..., the trick is to assume that this pointer can simply store an integer value.... Is this a problem? No,...._" -- sort of. `void *` is not an integer type to begin with, yet pointer types _can_ be converted to integer types; but, the result is implementation-defined, with potential undefined behavior if the resulting value can't be represented in the integer type; further: [The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6)

Comment: @exnihilo yes, thanks. I'm aware of that point, that's why I chose the vocabulary *thought about* and *trick* because it's only correct when we are lucky ;^) (respective size...) Do you suggest a better wording? (my English is limited)